# Java HTTP Post form and file

Tags: java, http-post, testfairy

So I want to use the TestFairy API (url: https://app.testfairy.com/api/upload). This API call expects 3 post paramters:

- `api_key` (string)
- `apk_file` (.apk file)
- `testers_groups` (string)

So far I came up with this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testers_groups", testers));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", key));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("apk_file", new FileBody(file));

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
    resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

But it does not work.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("api_key", new StringBody(key));
entity.addPart("apk_file", new FileBody(file));
entity.addPart("testers_groups", new StringBody(testers));
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Optionally add mime-types in the `StringBody` and `FileBody` constructors (but probably not necessary).